# Check certificate expiry along with Public key pinning

Tags: tls, certificate-pinning

Will public key pinning completely avoids the default server authentication process by client?

For example, by default server authentication process server checks for certificate expiry, By implementing public key pinning it means that only public key will verified, and the certificate expiry check that happens as part of default server authentication will not happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual public key pinning [as done in browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Public_Key_Pinning) is done additionally to the other validations. But one could implement public key pinning in specific applications so that it relies only on the key or certificate. This might make for example sense when the application developer controls both client and server and the server uses a self-signed certificate for authentication.

Comment: we are actullay implementing this for an iOS app. will it be the same case as with the browsers?

Comment: @Nareshsadu: this depends on the actual implementation

Comment: Thank you @Steffen Ullrich, I will open another question with actual implementation details, so that the question would be more specific.